# Entity Framework: Injecting dependencies into entities when other options are problematic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, structuremap, service-locator

I am working on a large C# enterprise project that has significant architectural problems. One of those problems is that there are static references to a StructureMap container all over the place (static service locator). As a first step to fixing things we are passing the container into constructors and removing the static container references.

Unfortunately there are calls to the static container in entities created by Entity Framework. Pushing all those dependencies up to the clients of those entities is not feasible to do right now because of the how frequently this happens and the scope of the changes. Our goal is to remove the static container and making that many changes to do it would not be allowed by management.

I would like to inject the container into the entities when they are created by Entity Framework instead, is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Moving the dependencies out of the entities and switching to dependency injection from service locator are part of the plan but one step at a time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember I read somewhere few years ago that services can be injected into entities through constructor, but I couldn't find it now, so maybe I was reading about [IDbDependencyResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680697(v=vs.113).aspx) which serves another purpose.

As a temporary solution I would suggest to mark entities with interface like `IHaveServiceLocator` and use [ObjectMaterialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
public interface IHaveServiceLocator
{
    IServiceLocator ServiceLocator { get; set; }
}
```

And then the place where you create dbContext should have access to service locator so you can set it to entities created.

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (s, e) =>
{
    var entity = e.Entity as IHaveServiceLocator;

    if (entity != null)
    {
        entity.ServiceLocator = structureMapServiceLocator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. It's nice to be able to just implement an interface and have the container injected.

Comment: this looks perfectly reasonable; however there are folk who would shout "servicelocator, ah! anti-pattern!". what would you say to them?

Comment: @jenson-button-event I definitely agree that service locator is anti-pattern and personally almost never use it. But sometimes it does the job and saves from rewriting entire code base like it this question.